# GWT finished Projct, how to bind it into Website

Tags: java, gwt, web

So i finished my GWT web Project, but how can i bind it into my website on funpic.de ?
I saerched but didnt find the right one.
Any good tutorial

Comment: look for "publishing the (gwt) project" on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to give your site some area on your page, you have two opportunities:

You can use an iFrame in your side and load your GWT app with the src-attribute.

```
<iframe src="TheGwtHTMLPage.html" width="90%" height="400px" />
```

or you can use a div-tag with an ID.

```
<div id="yourDivId"></div>
```

In this case you have to load your *.nocache.js (as always with a script-tag) and use

```
RootLayoutPanel.get("yourDivId").add(...);
```

The different between both is, if you use an iFrame, your GWT app can not access any information from your HTML page.